# Merge WAV audio and WebM video

Tags: node.js, wav, webm

There's a way to merge an audio (wav) and a video (webm) in a nodejs server?

Since WebM is a container format, I hope that is possible add audio track to an existing WebM file.
I'm right?

Anyone know a NodeJS package for doing this?

Comment: Should this package help me?
- whammy [https://npmjs.org/package/whammy]
- ncoder [https://npmjs.org/package/ncoder]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found a solution, but is not really simple to do.
For do this is required **ffmpeg** (or similar).

To install it I done this steps:

1. (only for mac) install [HomeBrew](http://brew.sh).
2. run the installation of ffmpeg with all the dependences that is required:

   `sudo brew install ffmpeg --with-libvpx --with-theora --whit-libogg --with-libvorbis`

   now we can merge a audio and a video file with this shell command:

   `ffmpeg -i video-file.webm -i audio-file.wav -map 0:0 -map 1:0 output-file-name.webm`

Here we can merge file from our shell, but what I needed was not this. I needed the capability to do this from a NodeJS server, and for doing this now we can run this code.

```
var util = require('util'),
  child_process = require('child_process');

var exec = child_process.exec;

function puts(error, stdout, stderr) {
  stdout ? util.print('stdout: ' + stdout) : null;
  stderr ? util.print('stderr: ' + stderr) : null;
  error ? console.log('exec error: ' + error) : null;
}

exec("ffmpeg -i video-file.webm -i audio-file.wav -map 0:0 -map 1:0 output-file-name.webm", puts);
```

This simple solution work fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this:

====> https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC/RecordRTC-to-Nodejs

====> https://github.com/schaermu/node-fluent-ffmpeg

Comment: Thanks for the advice! ;) I already use RecorderRTC for the recording but I create "my own package" for ffmpeg command... -_- I don't searched for a package... But now everything goes right! ;)