# Mixing video and audio files in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails app and I get as params in a controller two files. One is audio (WAV) and the other is video (webm).

I need to mix them together so that the output is a video (mp4) with the already mixed audio.

How can I do this?

Comment: The best way to do video mixing with ruby is not to use ruby...call an external program

Comment: It's a veritable bottomless pit, but you can use `ffmpeg`.  This SO answer might get you going: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263131/merge-wav-audio-and-webm-video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Meier pointed, using Ruby is not the way to go, but using an external program.

Once ffmpeg is installed on host you can run following command inside Rails to have a [mkv](http://www.finalmediaplayer.com/mkv-player.html) output video file:

```
`ffmpeg -i #{video_file.path} -i #{audio_file.path} -acodec copy -vcodec copy -f matroska output.mkv`
```